# Lombok issue - Could not find org.projectlombok

Tags: java, android, gradle, lombok

I get the following error, on a fresh android project with 2 modules and with just 5-6 new classes.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find org.projectlombok:lombok:.
     Required by:
         project :app

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

I cannot figure out what is going on, both of build.gradle files contain the lombok dependency

```
dependencies {
...
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'
}
```

Comment: Just looking at https://projectlombok.org/setup/gradle -- Do you need "testCompileOnly " and "testAnnotationProcessor " as well?

Comment: nope, same error

Comment: I'm less familiar with Gradle (more Maven), but I suspect someone who is will want to see your entire configuration file just to see if you've included the basic assumptions/requirements in the fresh project files you've generated. Maybe you can include that as well to help your question?

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue when I was using an `implementation platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:<VERSION>")` call in the `dependencies` block of a `build.gradle` file.

The issue was that it was applying the version automatically to my `compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok"` call but not `annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok"` call. I discovered this when running the `depdendencies` Gradle task on the project.

I'm still looking into why it isn't working for `annotationProcessor` definitions, but a workaround is to specify a version number in both the `compileOnly` and `annotationProcessor` calls and keep them in sync.

Comment: ´´´Specify a version number in both the compileOnly and annotationProcessor calls and keep them in sync.´´´ This did the trick for me.

Comment: The annotationProcessor issue can be fixed by also adding this:
`annotationProcessor platform('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:<VERSION>')` (see Evgeniy Kudlay's answer and my comment there)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of integrating lombok via the dependencies yourself you could try using the lombok-plugin and see if the problem still exists.

E.g.

```
plugins {
  id "io.freefair.lombok" version "5.3.0"
}
```

For further information on usage of the plugin please see: https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/io.freefair.lombok and https://docs.freefair.io/gradle-plugins/5.3.0/reference/

Answer (score 1):

If on Android Studio, you may want to check the following:

- that annotation processing is enabled (`Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Annotation Processors.`)
- that no extra lombok dependencies were inadvertently added to the `build.gradle` files besides the two you already listed. In my case I found an extra `implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'` dependency in app `build.gradle` file.
- that `mavenCentral()` is added to the list of repositories as below:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

After fixing those 3 issues lombok worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution for not working `annotationProcessor` definition without specifying version from a transitive dependency.

```
implementation platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:<VERSION>")
annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok"
```

to make it work need to add:

```
annotationProcessor "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:<VERSION>"
annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok"
```

found it here: [Why doesn't my annotationProcessor configuration see the version in my Gradle Platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70397868/why-doesnt-my-annotationprocessor-configuration-see-the-version-in-my-gradle-pl)

Comment: I guess this should be:
`annotationProcessor platform('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:<VERSION>')`
For me, together with
`implementation platform('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:<VERSION>')`,
this fixed my errors after removing the `io.spring.dependency-management` plugin (which caused other issues)