# Why doesn't my annotationProcessor configuration see the version in my Gradle Platform?

Tags: gradle

I'm using a [Gradle Platform](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html#sub:using-platform-to-control-transitive-deps) (specifically [`java-platform`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_platform_plugin.html)) to control my transitive dependencies. I have the following modules:

`platform/build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'java-platform'
}
dependencies {
    constraints {
        api('foo:bar:123')
    }
}
```

`app/build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.buildToolsVersion
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        maxSdkVersion rootProject.maxSdkVersion
        minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }
    
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility rootProject.sourceCompatibility
        targetCompatibility rootProject.targetCompatibility
    }
}

dependencies {
    api(platform(project(':platform')))

    annotationProcessor('foo:bar')
}
```

But when I run `./gradlew :app:dependencies`, gradle fails to find my `annotationProcessor` version:

```
debugAnnotationProcessorClasspath - Resolved configuration for annotation-processor for variant: debug
\--- foo:bar FAILED
```

If I specify the version explicitly, then everything works:

`app/build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.buildToolsVersion
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        maxSdkVersion rootProject.maxSdkVersion
        minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }
    
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility rootProject.sourceCompatibility
        targetCompatibility rootProject.targetCompatibility
    }
}

dependencies {    
    annotationProcessor('foo:bar:123')
}
```

And then I see the version in `./gradlew :app:dependencies`:

```
debugAnnotationProcessorClasspath - Resolved configuration for annotation-processor for variant: debug
\--- foo:bar:123
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `annotationProcessor` configuration represents a different dependency graph from your application classpath. It's completely independent, because it's dependencies which are "compiler plugins". So dependencies declared as `implementation ...` will *not* be found on the `annotationProcessor` path, and they must not. There's nothing different for your `platform` dependency here, so it's not because you declare a platform dependency on `implementation` that it will magically appear on the `annotationProcessor` path: there's no reason to do this.

Long story short: you need to declare your platform as a dependency of `annotationProcessor` too. Note that in absolute, there's no reason why you'd use the same dependency versions for your *compiler classpath* (the `annotationProcessor` path) and your *application classpath*: an annotation processor you use may for example depend on a different Guava version than your app, so it's a good idea to keep the platforms separate.

Answer (score 2):

I have to specify a Gradle Platform for every configuration I want to use it with, so

```
annotationProcessor(platform(project(':platform')))
```

This gradle issue provided a clue: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/8723

These module definitions worked:

`platform/build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'java-platform'
}
dependencies {
    constraints {
        api('foo:bar:123')
    }
}
```

`app/build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.buildToolsVersion
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        maxSdkVersion rootProject.maxSdkVersion
        minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }
    
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility rootProject.sourceCompatibility
        targetCompatibility rootProject.targetCompatibility
    }
}

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor(platform(project(':platform')))

    annotationProcessor('foo:bar')
}
```